# (Expected a value of type '(0 -> vold)?', but got one of type '_Future<dynamic»*)

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm not flutter expert and I'm trying to make an edit profile screen that updates user data to Laravel database but I get this error when running my screen

(Expected a value of type '(0 -> vold)?', but got one of type
'_Future<dynamic»*)

I can't fix it, can someone please help?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:udemy_flutter/Screens/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:udemy_flutter/auth_services.dart';
import 'package:udemy_flutter/globals.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


class EditProfileUI extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenRoute = 'EditProfileUI';
  const EditProfileUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _EditProfileUIState createState() => _EditProfileUIState();
}

class _EditProfileUIState extends State<EditProfileUI> {


  String _firstname = '';
  String _lastname = '';
  String _email = '';
  String _password = '';
  String _healthproblems = '';
  String _address = '';

  updatedataPressed() async {
    if (_firstname.isNotEmpty && _lastname.isNotEmpty && _email.isNotEmpty && _password.isNotEmpty
        && _healthproblems.isNotEmpty && _address.isNotEmpty) {
      http.Response response = await AuthServices.put(_firstname,_lastname,_email, _password, _healthproblems, _address);
      Map responseMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Navigator.push(
        //     context,
        //     MaterialPageRoute(
        //       builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomeScreen(),
        //     ));
      } else {
        errorSnackBar(context, responseMap.values.first);
      }
    } else {
      errorSnackBar(context, 'enter all required fields');
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2c363b),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2c363b),
        title: const Text('Profile'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Color(0xFFffae46),
          ), onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.screenRoute);
        },
        ),
      ),

      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 20, right: 15),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          },
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 130,
                      height: 130,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 4, color: Colors.white),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                spreadRadius: 2,
                                blurRadius: 10,
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1)
                            )
                          ],
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  ''
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                                width: 4,
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),



              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child: Column(
                  children: [

                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your First Name',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _firstname = value;
                      },
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your Last Name',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _lastname = value;
                      },
                    ),


                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your email',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _email = value;
                      },
                    ),




                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your password',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _password = value;
                      },
                    ),


                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your Health Problems',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _healthproblems = value;
                      },
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter your Address',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        _address = value;
                      },
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    

                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: updatedataPressed(),
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFffae46),
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                      ),
                      child: const Text("Save", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          letterSpacing: 2,
                          color: Colors.white
                      )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

```
static Future<http.Response> put(String firstname,String lastname,String email,
      String password, String healthproblems, String address) async {
    Map data = {
      "firstname" : firstname,
      "lastname" : lastname,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "healthproblems": healthproblems,
      "address": address,
    };
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var url = Uri.parse(editprofileURL + 'auth/update data');
    http.Response response = await http.put(
      url,
      headers: editprofileheaders,
      body: body,
    );
    print(response.body);
    return response;
  }
```

I have tried looking for solutions online but didn't help, like I mentioned I'm not an expert and I need it for my graduation project.

Answer (score 0):

In your design section, exactly here :

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: updatedataPressed(),
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFffae46),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                  ),
                  child: const Text("Save", style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 2,
                      color: Colors.white
                  )),
                )
```

in the elevated button "onPressed" parameters, try to make it like this :

```
 ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: (){
updatedataPressed();
},
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFffae46),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                  ),
                  child: const Text("Save", style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      letterSpacing: 2,
                      color: Colors.white
                  )),
                )
```

it should works

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a method tear-off:

```
updatedataPressed() async { ... }

ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: updatedataPressed,
)
```

I guess you called the method by accident.

The updatedataPressed method is defined as async. That means it will return a Future<SomeType>.

```
// Original code
updatedataPressed() async { ... }

// At compilation time it's equivalent to
dynamic updatedataPressed() async { ... }

// At runtime it's equivalent to
Future<dynamic> updatedataPressed() async { ... }

// When you call it, the returned value is Future<dynamic>
var future = updatedataPressed();

// If you await the Future the returned value will be null, because you didn't return anything
var value = await future; // null
```

The onPressed callback is declared as:

```
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();

final VoidCallback? onPressed;
```

You called the method by writing `updatedataPressed()` and gave the result (`Future<dynamic>`) to onPressed. Instead you want to pass a `void Function()` to onPressed by writing only `updatedataPressed`.

Edit: There are other ways to achieve the same result with different code. A few examples are `onPressed: () { updatedataPressed(); },`, `onPressed: () => updatedataPressed(),` and `onPressed: updatedataPressed,`. However, the last is the newest, shortest and most idiomatic way.